# How can I see the center of rotation of the 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view

Suppose I moved the center of the 3D view using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + middle mouse drag. Now the center of rotation is no longer in the center of the 3D view. Where is the center of rotation exactly? How can I see it?

Answer (score 2):

There may be another way but once you move the view if you press CTRL+ALT+Numpad 0 that will center a camera to the current view. The cameras position should now be the center of the rotation as well and you can get that info in the Item tab.